# Python: Why dosent this work?

Tags: python

So i have this small piece of code which just wont work:

```
 while c<b:
     str2 += str1[c]
     c+=1

print str2
```

b is the length of str1 that i want to copy to str2, and c is the point which i want to begin transfer from str1, then the while loop is just supposed to transfer all the characters from str1 to str2.

For some reason i can't seem to print str2 and get this error message:

"NameError: name 'str2' is not defined"

My guess is that I'm just doing something simple wrong, I just began experimenting with Python and have only really done C# before.

Comment: So.... is `str2` defined?

Comment: above that piece of code, where do you define your variables? do you have a line like `str2 =""` in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize `str2`:

```
str2 = ''
while c<b:
    str2 += str1[c]
    c+=1

print str2
```

Or else do a function that receives `str2` as parameter:

```
def myfunc(str2=''):
    while c<b:
        str2 += str1[c]
        c+=1

    return str2
```

where `str2` parameter is by default initialized as `''`, i.e. empty string.

Comment: Yep this does it. I was a bit confused a while with Python not accepting things such as "string" or "int" but this fixed my problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

A better approach would be to slice the strings:

```
str2 = str1[c:b]
```

This copies `str1` from character number `c` and up to character number `b` into `str2`.

For example:

```
>>> 'Hello World'[3:7]
'lo W'
```

Here's a little information about Python's slice notation: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: Beat me by just a few seconds :)

Comment: Doesn't @user1577913 want `str2 = str1[c:][:b]`?

Comment: @Neil: I think you're right. It's a bit late to change it, as the OP took the not-so-Pythonic route, but I seem to have misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
str2 += str1[c]
```

You are saying, "please add str1[c]" to whatever is already in `str2` .. the problem is that you haven't initialized `str2` with anything (at least in the code you show).

Easiest fix is to give `str2` an initial value before you use it in the loop, e.g., `str2=''`

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use something in the lines of:

```
str2 = str1[c:]
```